# Excel remove cells in export to CSV

Tags: excel, export-to-csv

I have a table in Excel that I have to export to CVS. The table is like:

[image]

I have the following code to export to CSV:

```
Columns("A:D").Copy
Workbooks.Add
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\x_test.csv" _
    , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

The output is like:

```
Book Title,,,
Author,Total Pages,Editor,Year Published
Adam,50,Universal,2018
Section,Pages,,
1,20,,
2,30,,
```

The problem I have is that it adds additional cells in rows that I don't need. for example, the first line should be like "Book Title" not like "Book Title,,,"

Is there a way to export to CSV with the relevant number of columns properly reflected with comas for each line

I tried merging the cells in Excel, but it did not make any difference.

Comment: It doesn't _add_ cells, the cells _are_ there (only they are empty). You may want to go through the csv after it is saved to remove the extraneous commas.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Following advice from @cybernetic.nomad I have resolved the issue with the following code:

```
Sub Example()
'Final string to print to file
Dim strFinal As String
'Line read from original text file
Dim strLine As String
'open the text file for reading
Open "C:\x_test.csv" For Input As #1
strFinal = ""
'loop until the end of the text file is reached
While EOF(1) = False
'read the current line from the text file
    Line Input #1, strLine
    'remove the commas
    If InStr(strLine, ",,,") > 0 Then
        strFinal = strFinal + Replace(strLine, ",,,", "") + vbCrLf 
    ElseIf InStr(strLine, ",,") > 0 Then
        strFinal = strFinal + Replace(strLine, ",,", "") + vbCrLf
    Else
        strFinal = strFinal + strLine + vbCrLf
    End If

Wend
strFinal = Left(strFinal, Len(strFinal) - 2)
'close the file
Close #1

'open the file for writing
Open "C:\x_test.csv" For Output As #1
Print #1, strFinal
'overwrite the file with the new string
Close #1
End Sub
```